# Drupal 7 form ajax callback show no radio items

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7, radio-button, drupal-forms

I have problem with drupal 7 and form ajax callback.

I have simple form with **form select** item and when i choose something ajax callback show item with **form radios**. Its actually works, but I get only radios item **title** and **description** but no options to choose.

```
function my_test_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['places'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select twitter trends location'),
    '#options' => array('1' => 'item 1', '2' => 'item 2'),
    '#default_value' => 1,
    '#description' => t('Select description'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'my_test_form_callback',
      'wrapper' => '.form-item.form-type-select.form-item-places',
      'method' => 'append',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );
  return $form;
}


function my_test_form_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['trends'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Select'),
    '#options' => array(0 => t('Closed'), 1 => t('Active')),
    '#default_value' => 0,
    '#description' => t('Radios description.'),
  );
  return $form['trends'];
}
```

result of print $form['trends'] -> `dpm(drupal_render($form['trends']));`

```
<div class="form-item form-type-radios">
  <label>Select trend </label>
  <div class="form-radios"></div>
  <div class="description">Radios description.</div>
</div>
```

I would be happy for every advice.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The callback receives a built form. It's only responsible for returning the right part of the form.

```
function my_test_form_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['trends'];
}
```

`my_test_form` is responsible for building the form for the first call and all the following AJAX calls. Simply put your condition inside this function.